# Spring OAuth2 client_credentials in combination with preauthenticated user

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

My app uses [preauthentication](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M1/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/JeeConfigurer.html)

I want to consume OAuth2 protected resources using `ClientCredentialsResourceDetails` (signed fetch).

When using this in combination with an preauthenticated `UserDetails`, spring does not store the OAuth token:

```
DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken@4662f11e: Principal: User = ***
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: I don't get the question yet, sorry. If you are pre-authenticated by your container, why do you need OAuth2, and where would you want the token to be stored anyway?

Comment: I want to consume an api that uses OAuth2 with client_credentials. Wouldn't it be best to store the token for the next request to save time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token is stored in memory in the `OAuth2RestTemplate`. That's good enough for most use cases because you can set it up as a singleton bean (one per client).